# redhat enterprise install python-devel, can not find python-devel

Tags: python, redhat, epel

I want to install python-devel on redhat enterprise 6.5.but yum search python-devel, find nothing. i install epel, then find:

```
ScientificPython-devel.i686 : The development files for ScientificPython
ScientificPython-devel.x86_64 : The development files for ScientificPython
nautilus-python-devel.i686 : Python bindings for Nautilus
nautilus-python-devel.x86_64 : Python bindings for Nautilus
qscintilla-python-devel.noarch : Development files for QScintilla PyQt4 bindings
wxPython-devel.i686 : Development files for wxPython add-on modules
wxPython-devel.x86_64 : Development files for wxPython add-on modules
```

but in centos, we can find the python-devel.
why and how i can install python-devel on redhat enterprise. i also try to find rmp package, but i did not find. i need  help.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Epel has no such package

```
curl "http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/" | grep python | awk '{ print $6 }' | grep devel
```

You could try grabbing the centos package and installing that? http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-devel&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=

For example:

```
curl -o python-devel-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/python-devel-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum install python-devel-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Note: Do not simply copy and paste the above text.  Make sure you grab the package matching your system and architecture.